# Why are antiparticles associated with spin-flipped spinors?

Tags: antimatter, dirac-equation, spinors, chirality, helicity

In section 2.2 of Elvang and Huang's Scattering Amplitudes in Gauge Theory and Gravity (http://arXiv.org/abs/1308.1697), beneath equation (2.9), it is mentioned that $u^{\pm}=v^{\mp}$, where $u^\pm$ are massless spinors corresponding to helicity eigenstates for particles, and $v^\mp$ are those for antiparticles.

Why is this true in general? Or is it a just a convention for associating certain antiparticle spinors with particle spinors? From equation (3.136) in section 3.6 of Peskin and Schroeder, we have$$v^s(p)=\begin{pmatrix}\sqrt{p\cdot\sigma}\xi^{-s}\\-\sqrt{p\cdot\bar{\sigma}}\xi^{-s}\end{pmatrix},$$ which seems to suggest that it is just a matter of *choosing* some basis of two-component spinors $\xi^{-s}$, which in this case happen to have opposite spin from those used in $u^{s}(p)$. With this choice of $v^s(p)$, it is straightforward to get $u^{\pm}=v^{\mp}$ in the massless limit.

I am sure that there is some physical justification for this but what is it? Elvang and Huang suggests using crossing symmetry but the choice of relating s and t channel diagrams seems as arbitrary as any convention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us say you decompose the Dirac field like the Klein-Gordon field, i.e.
$$\Psi(x)=\int[dk]\left(u(k)e^{-ikx}+v(k)e^{ikx}\right),$$
with the Lorentz-invariant integration measure $[dk]:=d^4k/(2\pi)^4\times2\pi\delta(k_0-\omega(\mathbf{k}))$, and define your positive- and negative-frequency solutions that way as $u,v$ respectively.

That means, if you interpret the solution $u$ as a Dirac fermion travelling in the direction $\mathbf{k}$ with positive frequency $k_0$, then $v$ is a Dirac fermion travelling into the direction $-\mathbf{k}$ with negative frequency $-k_0$. That is equivalent to saying that its Dirac-conjugate in $\int[dk]\overline{v}(k)e^{-ikx}$ is a Dirac-antifermion travelling in the direction $\mathbf{k}$ with positive frequency $k_0$.

Thus, while $u(k)$ is your Dirac-fermion, $\overline{v}(k)$ is your Dirac-antifermion. That interpretation makes sense since if you look at $e^+e^-$ annihilation, the incoming positron is described by the Dirac-conjugate $\overline{v}(k)$, and not $v(k)$.

So far so good, now we can look how the chirality projectors act on the Dirac-spinors. We define $u_{L/R}:=\frac{1}{2}(1\mp\gamma_5)u$ for the Dirac-fermion. Since $\overline{v}$ is the Dirac-antifermion, we should analogously define
$$\overline{v}_{L/R}:=\overline{v}\frac{1}{2}(1\mp\gamma_5)=v^\dagger\gamma^0\frac{1}{2}(1\mp\gamma_5)=v^\dagger\frac{1}{2}(1\pm\gamma_5)\gamma^0=\left(v_{R/L}\right)^\dagger\gamma^0=\overline{v_{R/L}}.$$

We see that the left-chiral Dirac-antifermion $\overline{v}_L=\overline{v_R}$ is a Dirac-conjugated right-chiral $v_R$. Note that the bars over the spinor have different lengths.

Now we do the last step and ditch the mass. Both $u$ and $v$ now fulfil the same Dirac equation $k_\mu\gamma^\mu u=0$, $k_\mu\gamma^\mu v=0$. The Dirac-spinors decompose into two decoupled Weyl-spinors $\hat{u}_{L/R}$, such that in the chiral representation $u_{L/R}=(\hat{u}_L,\hat{u}_R)^T$. These Weyl-spinors fulfil the Weyl equations
$$0=k_\mu\overline{\sigma}^\mu \hat{u}_L=k_0\hat{u}_L+k_i\sigma^i\hat{u}_L\leftrightarrow\frac{k_i\sigma^i}{|\mathbf{k}|}\hat{u}_L=-\hat{u}_L,$$
$$0=k_\mu\sigma^\mu \hat{u}_R=k_0\hat{u}_R-k_i\sigma^i\hat{u}_R\leftrightarrow\frac{k_i\sigma^i}{|\mathbf{k}|}\hat{u}_R=\hat{u}_R.$$
Here, we have used that $k_0=|\mathbf{k}|$ in the massless case to show that the chiral eigenstates are also helicity eigenstates for $m=0$: The left-chiral state has negative helicity, the right-chiral has positive helicity.

Since both $u$ and $v$ fulfill the same Dirac equation, the same two equations hold for the Weyl-spinors $\hat{v}_L,\hat{v}_R$. But as we should carefully remember, $v$ does not describe the antifermion - its Dirac-conjugated $\overline{v}$ does! In the chiral representation we have $\overline{v}=(\hat{v}^\dagger_L,\hat{v}^\dagger_R)$ and thus we have the Weyl equations
$$0=\hat{v}^\dagger_Rk_\mu\overline{\sigma}^\mu\leftrightarrow \hat{v}^\dagger_R\frac{k_i\sigma^i}{|\mathbf{k}|}=-\hat{v}^\dagger_R,$$
$$0=\hat{v}^\dagger_Lk_\mu\sigma^\mu\leftrightarrow \hat{v}^\dagger_L\frac{k_i\sigma^i}{|\mathbf{k}|}=\hat{v}^\dagger_L.$$
As we manifestly see, the left-chiral antifermion $\hat{v}^\dagger_L$ has positive helicity, unlike the left-chiral fermion $\hat{u}_L$. And the converse is true for the opposite chirality.

I must admit, I had to ponder a lot about this. The way I see it is that it is a typical case of '*be mindful about the maths in QFT and how you interpret it*'. Indeed, the idea is that one must be careful that both the fermion and the antifermion field should propagate into the same direction. If you interpret the exponential $e^{-i(\omega t-\mathbf{kx})}$ as a planar wave moving in direction $\mathbf{k}$, then $u$ is your fermion field and $\overline{v}$ is your antifermion field travelling in the same direction. From then on it is clear that $\overline{v}$ will dictate the antifermion's properties, not $v$. And the same then extends to the massless limit where the Dirac-spinors $u,\overline{v}$ are replaced by the Weyl-spinors $\hat{u}_{L/R},\hat{v}^\dagger_{L/R}$.