# What are the Feynman rules for the spinor-helicity formalism?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, spinors, helicity

If we do not work with helicity amplitudes, there are Feynman rules for the external legs of a Feynman diagram, i.e. $u_s(k),\overline{v}_s(k),\epsilon_r(k)$ for an incoming fermion, antifermion and gauge boson, respectively, and $\overline{u}_s(k),v_s(k),\epsilon^\ast_r(k)$ for their outgoing pendants.

Are these correct rules for external states in the spinor-helicity formalism?

| Particle & helicity | rule for incoming | rule for outgoing |
| --- | --- | --- |
| L-fermion | $u_L(k)=k]$ | $\overline{u}_L(k)=\langle k$ |
| R-fermion | $u_R(k)=k\rangle$ | $\overline{u}_R(k)=[k$ |
| L-antifermion | $\overline{v}_L(k)=\langle k$ | $v_L(k)=k]$ |
| R-antifermion | $\overline{v}_R(k)=[k$ | $v_R(k)=k\rangle$ |
| (+)-gauge boson | $\epsilon^\mu_+(k,r)=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\frac{[r\gamma^\mu k\rangle}{[rk]}$ | $\epsilon^{\mu\ast}_+(k,r)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\frac{[k\gamma^\mu r\rangle}{\langle rk\rangle}$ |
| (-)-gauge boson | $\epsilon^\mu_-(k,r)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\frac{[k\gamma^\mu r\rangle}{\langle rk\rangle}$ | $\epsilon^{\mu\ast}_-(k,r)=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\frac{[r\gamma^\mu k\rangle}{[rk]}$ |

Here, $r$ shall be an arbitrary reference momentum with $r^2=0,rk\neq0$, and of course all fermions shall be massless.

Comment: I do not know why the table is not rendered correctly. I have written it as is explained in the help section in the text editor. Suggestions how to fix this are welcome or maybe a moderator would correct my formatting and tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: Fixed (you just needed to add a newline before the table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table I have given turns out to be wrong for the antifermions. As I have explained in [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/616697/141565), a left-chiral antifermion $\overline{v}_L=(v_R)^\dagger\gamma_0$ is described by the Dirac-conjugate of a right-chiral Dirac-spinor $v_R$. That means, $v_R(k)=k]\leftrightarrow\overline{v}_L(k)=[k$ and conversely $v_L(k)=k\rangle\leftrightarrow\overline{v}_R(k)=\langle k$.

All this can now be put into a neat table.

| Particle & helicity | rule for incoming | rule for outgoing |
| --- | --- | --- |
| L-fermion | $u_L(k)=k]$ | $\overline{u}_L(k)=\langle k$ |
| R-fermion | $u_R(k)=k\rangle$ | $\overline{u}_R(k)=[k$ |
| L-antifermion | $\overline{v}_L(k)=[k$ | $v_L(k)=k\rangle$ |
| R-antifermion | $\overline{v}_R(k)=\langle k$ | $v_R(k)=k]$ |
| (+)-gauge boson | $\epsilon^\mu_+(k,r)=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\frac{[r\gamma^\mu k\rangle}{[rk]}$ | $\epsilon^{\mu\ast}_+(k,r)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\frac{[k\gamma^\mu r\rangle}{\langle rk\rangle}$ |
| (-)-gauge boson | $\epsilon^\mu_-(k,r)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\frac{[k\gamma^\mu r\rangle}{\langle rk\rangle}$ | $\epsilon^{\mu\ast}_-(k,r)=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\frac{[r\gamma^\mu k\rangle}{[rk]}$ |